# show/hide child elements of <li> with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach

I have a razor loop on my .cshtml page in my mvc 4 project and I need to show hide the children of a list within this razor loop.
The code works for the first element but not for the rest.

.cshtml code

```
<ol>
    @foreach (var Name in (List<string>)ViewData["Names"])
    {
        <li onclick="makevisible();" ondblclick="makeinvisible();">
            @Name
            <ul id="list" class="list">
                <li>childWichNeedsToBeHidden</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
</ol>
```

My javascript:
`function makevisible() {$('#list').show();}`
and:
`function makeinvisible() {$('#list').hide();}`

My css: `.list {display:none;}`

## EDIT

my new .cshtml code

```
    @{
      int i = 0;
      foreach (var Name in (List<string>)ViewData["Names"])
      {
          i++;
          <li onclick="makevisible();" ondblclick="makeinvisible();">
            @Name
             <ul class="list" id="@i">
                <li>childWichNeedsToBeHidden</li>
             </ul>
          </li>
      }
    }
```

So now each ul has a unique id. But I do not know what my javascript should be.
I can show hide a specific child ul like the third one with:

```
        function makevisible() {
            $('#3').show();
        }
        function makeinvisible() {
            $('#3').hide();
        }
```

how do I make the #3 a variable so that i can show hide any child ul i want?

Comment: you should have different ids for each of the UL element

Comment: Unique Ids please or access then via Class . not Ids #

Comment: unique id's + access via class...

Comment: Thanks. However if I access by class when I click on one list item the children of all the list items are revealed. So maybe I need a for-each in my java-script to give all the list items unique ID's?

Answer (score 2):

You should try with

```
function makevisible() {
    $(this).find('.list').show();
}

function makeinvisible() {
    $(this).find('.list').hide();
}
```

you should not use same id for ul in foreach.

Comment: Nothing happened onclick when I tried this. $('.list').show(); works but it shows the children of all the ul elements onclick which i do not want either!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol>
    @foreach (var Name in (List<string>)ViewData["Names"])
    {
        <li class="parentLI" onclick="makevisible();" ondblclick="makeinvisible();">
            @Name
            <ul class="list">
                <li>childWichNeedsToBeHidden</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
</ol>
```

And your script should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){

  $(".parentLI").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("ul.list").hide();
});

});
</script>
```

Bind the `dblclick` event in the same way

Comment: Nothing happens onclick when I try this. I think it is to do with the use of '$(this)'